# JPA : Insert happening twice during bean MERGE CASCADE and beforeTransactionCompletion: Hence SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

INSERT is happening twice, hence the error java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

What I dont understand is that once the CASCADE happened and DB is created/updated with entities info, why again entities were found as DIRTY and again called for INSERT/UPDATE on DB during flush/cascade of beforeTransaction completed.

Could anyone please help me.
I tried all possible ways to make it work, but couldn't succeed.
 Please help me.

### Data Model:

### Entities Definition:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class RDBMSRoleBean {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assocRole", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<RoleResourcePermBean> resourceAssociations = new ArrayList<RoleResourcePermBean>();

}


@Entity
public class RoleResourcePermBean {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private RDBMSRoleBean assocRole;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ResourcePermBean associatedResource;
}

@Entity
public class ResourcePermBean {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "associatedResource", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<RoleResourcePermBean> roleResourcePermLocal = new ArrayList<RoleResourcePermBean>();
}
```

### Creating the RoleResourcePermBean :

```
RoleResourcePermBean bean = new RoleResourcePermBean(role.getRoleId(),
                            new Integer((int) permissions[i]), authorized);
                    bean.setAssocRole(role);
                    role.getResourceAssociations().add(bean);

                    permBean = findByPrimaryKey(ResourcePermBean.class, new Integer((int) permissions[i]));
                    bean.setAssociatedResource(permBean);
                    permBean.getRoleResourcePermLocal().add(bean);
```

Comment: Can you also post the code parts where you are performing the save/update to DB?

Comment: can you please tell details regarding the ALLOWED column in insert query?found in insert query in log section

Comment: Why would you declare the `@JoinColumn`s as `insertable=false, updatable=false`? You do realize that neither of the two associations is getting stored, right?

Comment: @pleft: I am updating a Role and adding necessary privilages to the role and the calling the merge on entity manager.                                           
 aRole = CAAFEntityUtil.findByPrimaryKey(RDBMSRoleBean.class, role);

   // update the description
   if (description != null) {
    aRole.setDescription(description);
   }
   
   // Update positive and negative permissions
   aRole.setPermissions(positivePermissions, negativePermissions);
   em.merge(aRole);

Comment: @akhilsk : It is the column, which accepts values +/-, indicated authorization of the permission to a Role

Comment: @crizzis: actually I dont much idea of these insertable/updateble flags, but it does store the data in DB.

Comment: @Crizzis  may be because parent table and child table has the same column name. Hence it may gets stored in DB. If i these flags, then i would get error "Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.convergys.security.entity.rdbms.RoleResourcePermBean column: ROLE (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\")"}}"

Comment: `insertable=false, updatable=false` tells Hibernate to ignore the column in any `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. I don't see any duplicate mappings in any of your entities, so unless you're not showing us something, there shouldn't really be any errors.

Comment: @SrinivasaReddyPapana but i didnt see mentions about that ALLOWED column in your entity class

Comment: @akhilsk actually i had mentioned only entity mappings. Here are the other columns:                                            
        Id
 Column(name = "ROLE")
 private String role;
 Column(name = "ALLOWED")
 private String allowed;
 id
 Column(name = "RESOURCE_ID")
 private Integer resourceId;

Comment: @crizzis as mentioned in previous comment, entity RoleResourcePermBean has other columns. If I remove intertable and updatables flag from JoinColumn, then the deployment failed with error"..."Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.convergys.security.entity.rdbms.RoleResourcePermBean column: ROLE (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\")"}}"

Comment: Something is wrong with your mapping, then. Please post the *entire* entity mappings

Answer (score 0):

May be issue was due to that I had 2 instances of EntityManager.
Actually I am using SessionBeans for facade for all my JPA Entity beans.
And I got the code in the Session Bean to instantiate the EntityManager, but some how the entity manager object 'em' didnt initialized(not sure whats wrong). Hence I got the below code snipper to get create the object from the EntityManagerFactory. And I was having Util Class to get the same, but somehow got created 2 entity objects. 
Now I fixed the issue like whatever the entity manager object is created, i am setting same to util class so that only one entity manager object exists throughout a session.
:

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PFJPAEMJTA")
    private EntityManager em;

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PFJPAEMJTA");
                    em1 = em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Persistence.xml:

org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
.......

Comment: The above one fixes some flows. Now running into another error in UPDATE flow:         TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a7009f7:-550ca19b:59c4e198:117, org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization@3e637dc7 >: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.convergys.security.entity.rdbms.RoleResourcePermBean#RoleResourcePermPK [role=CAAFPermissionUpdate, resourceId= 105]]